# how to partition a graph(matrix) into subdomains with different sizes

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, domain-decomposition, partitioning

i am studying the solver for PageRank problems which drived from the web link graph.

I have tried using METIS to divided the matrix into subdomains, but METIS can only produce subdomains with nearly equal size. For the web link graph, it usually has blocks with different sizes because the domain or host of pages has different sizes.

So, i want to find a method to divide the graph to subdomain with different sizes adaptively. Is there such a method or how can i do this?

Thank you

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to adapt for or what your end goal is. Are you solving the eigenvalue problem for the PageRank algorithm? The manner in which you decompose the matrix to solve this problem in parallel should not affect the solution you get. Or are you examining the more general problem of network [community detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_structure)?

Answer (score 3):

If different nodes have different costs, for example because different rows of your matrix have different numbers of nonzero entries, then you need to attach *weights* to each node of your graph. Graph partitioning algorithms such as METIS allow you to do this, creating partitions where it is not the number of nodes that are about equal between partitions, but where the sum of weights of nodes are about equal.